# Swift problems with loading data into UITableView using dictionary keys and values

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, dictionary

Im a beginner to developing apps and I'm trying to create my first real app using Xcode/Swift.

The problem I am having is setting up a table view to show certain information. I've managed to create other table views successfully but this one is slightly more complicated. I'll start off by breaking it down.

I have a variable that receives data via a segue called `var recievedSelection = (choice: "", choiceValue:0.0)`  'choice' being the name of selection and 'choiceValue' being the cost of that selection.

I then store this data into a dictionary array called `var dict:[String:Double] = ["":0.0]` by using this line of code:

```
self.dict[self.recievedSelection.choice] = self.recievedSelection.choiceValue
```

I have a table view all set up with delegate methods etc working and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("basic", forIndexPath: indexPath)`. The numberOfSectionInTableView return 1 and numberOfRowsInSection return self.dict.count

What I am having problems with is using the data of each 'key' of self.dict to set as the `cell.textLabel?.text` and the data of each 'value' of self.dict to set as the `cell.detailTextLabel?.text` so that when the tableView loads the name and price of that selection is visible in each cell. Once user has made all their selections/choices as there will be a few to make throughout the app, there should be a list of those selections/choices that can be viewed in this table view.

Then there is a "Total" amount at the bottom just under the table view that calculates the overall amount.

I have also set up the table view to delete individual cells that when  and if a cell is deleted that amount/price set into that cell is deducted from the total at the bottom of screen.

I am using `NSUserDefaults` to save the data loaded into the table view as there isn't any personal data being stored and it is only a brief estimate.

But the problem is, I can't get the table view to load both the values and keys of 'self.dict' into the table view `textLabel` and the `detailTextLabel`?

I hope that makes sense! I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: While your post is thorough, I'm struggling to see what your actual problem is. Saying something "isn't working" isn't good enough. Can you provide any examples what you have tried, what result you are getting, and what you actually want?

Comment: So, you want to get each entry in a Dictionary, with an integer value (indexPath.row)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you want to get values for your UITableViewDataSource from a Dictionary. An Array would be better, and you can likely change your code to use one for the UIViewController's data, but if you must, first get a set of the Dictionary's keys into an Array:

```
var myDataSource = Array(self.dict.keys)
```

Reassign this value EVERY TIME you edit/delete from the Dictionary, before you call tableView.reloadData(), to avoid index out of bounds crashes. Now, in your dataSource methods, you can check

```
self.dict[myDataSource[indexPath.row]]
```

and

```
myDataSource[indexPath.row]
```

and

```
return self.dict.count
```

This will give you both the size of the array that you need for number of rows, and the value and key you need from your Dictionary. If you like, you can also iterate over a Dictionary's keys and values with:

```
for (key, value) in self.dict {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Using your code above the tableView loads the key into tableView fine but i am having problems loading the value data into the cell as the detailTextLabel.  I have put the following into cellForRowAtIndexPath -

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("basic", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        var myDataSource = Array(self.dict.keys)
        cell.textLabel!.text = myDataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.dict[myDataSource[indexPath.row]]
        cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named:"trash_empty")!)
        cell.accessoryView!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)
            return cell

    }
I do apologise if this is wrong

Comment: It looks right. What does the line cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.dict[myDataSource[indexPath.row]] give you?

Comment: I am getting an error, ambiguous reference to member subscript. I will try code below

Comment: Also, you need to cast your UITableViewCell, as the custom class that has a detailTextLabel. You do this by       let cell : myCustomCellType = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("basic", forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! myCustomCellType. The code you have will give you a generic UITableViewCell, which means that 'cell.detailTextLabel?.text' won't actually assign the value.

Comment: The 'ambiguous member subscript' just the compiler, unsure about whether myDict is a Dictionary, and myDataSource is an Array. Use var myDataSource : [String] = Array(self.dict.keys). I think that should solve that half of the problem. You may also want to separate that line into two : let key = myDataSource[indexPath.row] as String and cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.dict[key], if you're still having problems.

Comment: This gives me an error use of undeclared type 'myCustomCellType'

Comment: I was using that as a placeholder, because it looks like you're using a  custom UITableViewCell. Replace those with the class name of your custom cell. It's the same reason I used 'myDataSource'. You can and should name the var and class what you wish. I use 'self.dict, because you listed the name of that var in your original post. Sorry, I know it's a bit confusing, but communication can be difficult when I don't have your full code.

Comment: Ok i do apologise, im a little confused. This is what I've currently got -

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("basic", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        var myDataSource : [String] = Array(self.dict.keys)
        cell.textLabel!.text? = self.dict[key]
        cell.detailtextLabel.text? = myDataSource[indexPath.row] as String
        cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named:"trash_empty")!)
        cell.accessoryView!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)
            return cell

Comment: This is giving me 2 errors, use of unresolved identifier 'key' and value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'detailTextLabel' I did change the tableViewCell to 'custom' in attributes inspector

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake, I think. One step at a time: You're just using a UITableViewCell, not a custom subclass? In that case what you're missing is to undo the Attribute Inspector change, and to replace the line 'cell.detailtextLabel.text? = myDataSource[indexPath.row] as String ' with two lines: 'let key = myDataSource[indexPath.row] as String' and 'cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.dict[key]'.  If not, let me know.

Comment: 'Use of unresolved identifier 'key'' means that you haven't defined key, yet. You skipped the line of the code I offered: 'let key = myDataSource[indexPath.row] as String'

Comment: I think we are getting there! It now giving me an error, cannot assign value of type double? to type String?

Comment: That's easy! Find the line, and the value that is a Double? (Optional Double, I assume). Cast it to a string, either by using the description property of the unwrapped Double : 'myDouble!.description', or unwrapping it in a new String : '"\(myDouble!)"'. Again, 'myDouble' is a placeholder I'm using, for whatever your Double? var is.

Comment: I changed it to this String (self.dict[key]) and that got rid of the error. I will run it and see if it works

Comment: ok so now i am getting nothing at all loading into the cell.textLabel BUT the detailTextLabel(Double) loads perfectly!

Comment: Well, you said the line 'cell.textLabel!.text = myDataSource[indexPath.row] ' loaded that label perfectly. Replace whatever you have now with this original.

Comment: Its working!! Thank you so much and I'm sorry I'm a bit slow to catch on, its all a bit new to me atm. Just one last question,when a user deletes a cell i need to put some code into - func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete { But how would you suggest i remove that particular cell amount(Double) from the 'total' variable, i use the original passed data on viewDidLoad to add the cost into 'total' but i now need to deduct the cell amount

Comment: What is "total"? Is it a property of your View Controller? And does the table view use it, in any way?

Comment: "Total" is a variable of ViewController. The tableView doesn't use it. I use the original passed data to viewController and store the the overall amount/cost in "Total" like so -  if self.recievedValue > 0 {
            self.total = self.recievedValue + self.totalValue
            self.totalLabel.text = "Total: \(self.total)"

Comment: Okay. If the table view isn't using it, then you should be able to set it whenever you like. The one thing to be aware of, is to ALWAYS update your data set, before reloading your table (which is done if you call deleteRowAtIndexPath(), or reloadData() ). I'd handle it in this order: delete the entry from self.dict, update your table view, then update the total.

Comment: So I'm not really sure how to access the amount (value) of the cell, i used this code but getting several errors - self.dict.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
        self.total - self.dict.keys
        self.totalLabel.text = "Total: \(self.total)"
        self.saveState()

Comment: Alright, first: To remove a value from your Dictionary with just an index path and table view, you need to call self.dict.removeValueForKey(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath.textLabel!.text!). There's a lot to unpack there, and you may want to take a tutorial on how Dictionaries and Arrays work, as there seems to be some confusion.

Comment: Second (though it sounds like you want to do this first), to get the value, you similarly access the value of the Dictionary, for that key: self.dict[tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath.‌​textLabel!.text!].

Comment: calling this -  self.dict.removeValueForKey(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath.‌​textLabel!.text!) gives an error value of type (NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell has no member 'textLabel'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the param for that cell for row method. Try this: 'tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)'; keep everything else the same.

Comment: Ok so I'm really sorry but once again I'm not sure where we are at. I have this (with errors) -  self.dict.removeValueForKey(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath.‌​textLabel!.text!)
        tableView.reloadData()
        self.total - self.dict[tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath).‌​textLabel!.text!‌​]
        self.totalLabel.text = "Total: \(self.total)"

Comment: Two problems: 1) you need to subtract from the total, BEFORE you remove the entry from the dict (the removeValueForKey line). Otherwise, you'll be pulling the wrong value, or getting nil, if you're at the end of the table. 2) You didn't add the (indexPath) to the cellForRowAtIndexPath method in the first line, only the second. You need it in both. Also, I have to get some sleep, soon. I suggest taking this one step at a time: make sure you're getting the total correct first, then move on to removing the value, and try updating the table, after you know those are working.

Comment: A big part of the reason this is taking so long, is that you keep trying to solve everything at once, and have some misunderstandings/things you haven't figured out, yet, about how the language works

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your help AND patience! I will have a break from it for now and go back to it tomorrow. I will take a look at some more dictionary and array tutorials, try to break it down. I really appreciate all of your advice and time you have given me today. Sleep well!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure from your question what is causing the problem, meaning i'm not sure which value you  are not getting.  However, you can get those values by using:

```
let keyArray = dict.allKeys
```

then in your cellForIndexPath:

```
cell.textLabel.text? = keyArray[indexPath.row] //the "key"'s Value
cell.detailtextLabel.text? = dict[keyArray[indexPath.row]] // the "value"s value
```

Hope this helps your issue?

Comment: This gives me an error value of type '[string: Double]' has no member 'allKeys'

Comment: I'm sorry it's actually dict.keys now, swift3 changes still haven't stuck with me completely yet lol